# Using npm as custom plugin manager?

Tags: node.js, plugins, npm

Think of sublime text, where you can install or uninstall plugins. I want that for my app, and I want to use npm/github to do it.

Maybe I'll require that your package starts with `myapp-` to be considered a plugin for my app. How can I search npm based on that, and also install/update packages into the folder I want (not node_modules) and ideally it should work even if the person doesn't have npm installed (using an http api?).

Plugins for my app go into `plugins/plugin-name` folder, all I need to do is download their git source into that folder

Comment: This is a good idea, but Stack Overflow is the wrong forum to present it.

Comment: Fair enough, SO is the only forum I know. I'll answer this question myself eventually

Comment: Be that as it may, there's a pretty narrow focus here. There are [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) for more open-ended discussion.

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar have a look at how yeoman does that. Its pretty much the same what you are asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://api-docs.npms.io/ has an http API for searching npm packages.

Which can be used like this: https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=keywords:myapp to get all plugins for myapp

To actually download/install an npm package into any folder, I found an npm package called [download-npm-package](https://github.com/kesla/download-npm-package) that lets me do it in code

Answer (score 1):

I have created a project to solve similar problems. See [live-plugin-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-plugin-manager).

You can install, uninstall and load plugins from npm at runtime.

```
import {PluginManager} from "live-plugin-manager";
import * as path from "path";

const manager = new PluginManager({
  pluginsPath: path.join(__dirname, "plugins")
});

async function run() {
  await manager.installFromNpm("moment");

  const moment = manager.require("moment");
  console.log(moment().format());

  await manager.uninstall("moment");
}

run();
```

In the above code I install `moment` package at runtime, load and execute it. Here I have used typescript, but the same can be written with plain javascript.

Plugins are installed inside the directory specified in the `PluginManager` constructor or in the `plugins` directory if not specified.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a great module, for enhancements like your proposal:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kawix/core

You can read the README.md, for try understand the usage, i will add a basic example:

```sh
> npm install -g @kawix/core
> kwcore  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/voxsoftware/kawix-core/master/example/npmrequire/express.js"
```

And this is the content of file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/voxsoftware/kawix-core/master/example/npmrequire/express.js

```
// this will download the npm module and make a local cache
import express from 'npm://express@^4.16.4'


var app = express() 
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
}) 
app.listen(3000)
console.log("Listening on 3000")
```